# How would I parse json from an external url?

Tags: javascript, json

I am relatively new to js. I want to be able to parse json from an external url using pure javascript. At the moment I am using

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status === 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
  } else {
    callback(status, xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.send();
 };

 function statsget() {
 var uname = document.getElementById("nameget").value;
 var data = getJSON(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${uname}/circle.json`);
 var stats = JSON.parse(data);
 alert(data.is_betrayed);
 }
```

this however is not working. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: you suppose to define your callback function and pass it as a second parameter to `getJSON` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you forgot to pass callback function to getJSON as second parameter, which is supposed to be called 
when your xhr returns with the data.
Second, you do not need to parse data to json when you are asking for JSON file from server and setting responseType to JSON, this would be automatically done for you.

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status === 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
  } else {
    callback(status, xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.send();
 };


function yourCallBackFunction(err, data){
    if(err){
        //Do something with the error 
    }else{
        //data  is the json response that you recieved from the server
    }

}

 function statsget() {
 var uname = document.getElementById("nameget").value;
 var data = getJSON(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${uname}/circle.json`, yourCallBackFunction);

 }
```

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: so A call back function is the function that takes the data and does something with it? so in else part of the callback funtion I could put alert(data.is_betrayed) ?

Comment: callback functions are just simple functions which are passed around to asynchronous calls(in above case its the xhr request).These async calls happen at OS level and seperate from where your javascript code is executing hence you pass a function and ask the async call to invoke this callback function when it is finished.So basically when the xhr request finishes it calls your callback function with the data.
For more details you can you can read https://medium.com/@gaurav.pandvia/understanding-javascript-function-executions-tasks-event-loop-call-stack-more-part-1-5683dea1f5ec

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure Javascript, there's already a built-in way to do that without writing your own function:

```js
 function statsget() {
   var uname = 'CertainPerformance';
   fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${uname}/circle.json`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(resJSON => {
       // interact with resJSON here
       console.log(resJSON);
     });
 }
 statsget();
```

Promises are a whole lot nicer to work with than callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a callback function defined in your `statsget` method. Something like this.

```
function statsget() {
 var uname = document.getElementById("nameget").value;
 getJSON(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${uname}/circle.json`, 
    function(data) {
      var stats = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.is_betrayed);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working in the way you expecting it to because of you not using  `callback` function (even though you have it in your `getJSON` function as parameter you passing)

The thing is - this function suppose to be called after you get the response.
Add something like this to check

```
var processingData = function(status, data){
    console.log("my data is here:\n", data);
    if(status == null) { 
       return data;
    }
}

 function statsget() {
     var uname = document.getElementById("nameget").value;
     var data = getJSON(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${uname}/circle.json`, processingData);
     var stats = JSON.parse(data);
     alert(data.is_betrayed);
 }
```