# Why can't this json retrieving code work?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get som info from google's map api using pure javascript. For that I query a given address in order to retrieve the relevant info. I've been googling around and found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623022/how-would-i-parse-json-from-an-external-url), but something isn't working: the traces I've set with console.log won't appear on the console.

Here's my code

```
function getZipcode(address){
            if(address){
                //Formatted address
                console.log("address  "+ address);
                var formattedAddr = address.split(' ').join('+');
                console.log("formattedAddr  "+ formattedAddr);
                //Send request and receive json data by address
                var url1 = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + formattedAddr +'&sensor=true_or_false';
                console.log("url1  "+ url1);


                var geocodeFromAddr ;//= get_json(url1);
                // recuperar json
                console.log("pre geocodeFromAddr " );
                geocodeFromAddr = function(url1, trataJSON) {
                    console.log("geocodeFromAddr " );
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', url1, true);
                    xhr.responseType = 'json';
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        console.log("geocodeFromAddr onload " );
                        var status = xhr.status;
                        console.log("geocodeFromAddr status " + status );                           
                        if (status === 200) {
                            trataJSON(null, xhr.response);
                        } else {
                            trataJSON(status, xhr.response);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                    };
                    console.log("post geocodeFromAddr " );
            }
        }
```

and here my callback

```
function trataJSON(err, data){
            console.log("trataJSON " );
            if(err){
                console.log("trataJSON error " + err);
            }else{
                console.log("trataJSON ok " + data);
            }
        }
```

I'm testing with "calle pintor oliet 4 castellon" and the logs on the console are:

> query = calle pintor oliet 4 castellon
>
> address calle pintor oliet 4 castellon
>
> formattedAddr calle+pintor+oliet+4+castellon
>
> url1  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=calle+pintor+oliet+4+castellon&sensor=true_or_false
>
> pre geocodeFromAddr
>
> post geocodeFromAddr

You can see that - apparently - it never gets in the geocodeFromAddr piece of the code. Also you can check that the google apis URL is working correctly - not returning errors at all.

Can somebody please point me to some clues?

Comment: Well, you are only assigning a function to `geocodeFromAddr`. You're never hooking up that function to any callback or are calling it in any way…

Comment: you'll also need an API key from google

Comment: I used the accepted response from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623022/how-would-i-parse-json-from-an-external-url   What am I missing?

Comment: In that answer there's a call to `getJSON()`. In yours there isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I parse json from an external url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623022/how-would-i-parse-json-from-an-external-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in Chrome if you are targeting any other browser might need a Polyfill for fetch.

```js
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=calle+pintor+oliet+4+castellon&sensor=true_or_false')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(d => {
            if (d.results && d.results.length) {
                let address_components = d.results[0].address_components;
                let postalCode = {};
                address_components.forEach(addressComponent => {
                    if(addressComponent.types.includes("postal_code")){
                        postalCode = addressComponent;
                    }
                })
                console.log(postalCode);
                console.log('Postal Code:->', postalCode.long_name);
            }
        })
```